# Django url path converter not working in production

Tags: django, production, url-parameters, urlparse

I'm using path converter in my django app like so:

```py
# urls.py

from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
  path('articles/<str:collection>', views.ArticleView),
]


# views.py

@login_required
def ArticleView(request, collection):
    print(collection)
    if collection == "None":
        articles_query = ArticleModel.objects.all()
    ...
```

This works fine in development for a url suck as : `http://localhost:8000/articles/My Collection` which gets encoded to `http://localhost:8000/articles/My%20Collection`, and is decoded properly in the ArticleView. However, in development, I have to edit the view like so to get it to work:

```py
# views.py

import urllib.parse

@login_required
def ArticleView(request, collection):
    collection = urllib.parse.unquote(collection)
    print(collection)
    if collection == "None":
        articles_query = ArticleModel.objects.all()
    ...
```

Otherwise, the `print(collection)` shows My%20Collection and the whole logic in the rest of the view fails.

```
requirements.txt

asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.1.1
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
django-floppyforms==1.9.0
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.8
lxml==4.5.2
Pillow==7.2.0
python-pptx==0.6.18
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
XlsxWriter==1.3.3
pymysql
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "This happens in the admin interface as well." can you be more specific about what happens there?

Comment: I was wrong, the issue I was having in the admin interface was unrelated, I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is being urlencoded which encodes spaces as `%20`. There are a number of other encodings. As you've discovered you need to decode that parameter in order to compare it to what you'd expect. As you've likely realized, if you have a value that actually wants `The%20News` and not `The News`, you have no recourse. To handle this people will create a slug field. [Django has a model field for this in the framework.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield)

This is typically a URL-friendly, unique value for the record.

Assuming you add a `slug = models.SlugField()` to `ArticleModel`, your urls and view can change into:

```
urlpatterns = [
  # Define a path without a slug to identify the show all code path and avoid the None sentinel value.
  path('articles', views.ArticleView, name='article-list'),
  path('articles/<slug:slug>' views.ArticleView, name='article-slug-list'),
]


@login_required
def ArticleView(request, slug=None):
    articles_query = ArticleModel.objects.all()
    if slug:
        articles_query = articles_query.filter(slug=slug)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your detailed answered. I understand the need for a slug field, however, I still don't understand why not using a slug field like I do worked fine in development but doesn't work correctly in production ?

Comment: It seems like `runserver` is auto decoding the parameters. I wonder if that operates differently than the web server you're using.

Comment: This is probably what's going on, I'll try to get more infos on that. Thanks you very much!